Azure Cost Exports - Parquet format parsing in Java
I have exported the azure cost data to the storage account in parquet format. while parsing that file getting data output as GenericData$Fixed in bytes. I don't know how to get the original value from this.
I tried toString() that also returns the same. Tried BigInteger that also not works
The data type is org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Fixed
My code is
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> reader = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        
        try
        {
            in = new FileInputStream(new File("part_1_0001.parquet"));
            
            ParquetStream parquetStream = new ParquetStream(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), in);
            
            ParquetConfiguration conf = new PlainParquetConfiguration();
            conf.set(org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroReadSupport.READ_INT96_AS_FIXED, "true");
            
            reader = AvroParquetReader
                    .<GenericRecord>builder(parquetStream,conf)
                    .build();

            GenericRecord record;
            
            while ((record = reader.read()) != null) 
            {
                Object fieldValue = record.get(42); 
              // fieldValueOutput - [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 121, -61, -40, 0]
                
            }
                    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
...
        }
        finally
        {
            if(reader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
            if(in!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    in.close(); 
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

Anyone guide me to get the original value from this.

I'd suggest trying to read Parquet files in Spark, otherwise Avro fields are gotten by string name, not number


Azure Cost Exports - Parquet format parsing in Java

I agree with OneCricketeer's comment, you can use Spark. it will automatically decode Parquet schemas, including complex types like Avro fields, without you needing to manually decode byte arrays.
Here is the code to read the parquet file with spark and scala using java.
Code:
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize Spark session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Parquet Reader")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        // Read the Parquet file into a DataFrame
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().parquet("data.parquet");
        df.printSchema();
        df.show();
        df.select("your_field_name").show();
        spark.stop();
    }
}

Output:
root
 |-- column0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column1: string (nullable = true)

+---------+--------+
|  column0| column1|
+---------+--------+
|    first|    last|
|    Jorge|   Frank|
|   Hunter|  Moreno|
|   Esther|  Guzman|
|   Dennis|Stephens|
|   Nettie|Franklin|
|  Stanley|  Gibson|
|  Eugenia|   Greer|
|  Jeffery| Delgado|
|    Clara|   Cross|
|  Bernice|    Vega|
|    Kevin|    Diaz|
|Henrietta|  Rivera|
|  Matilda|   Ellis|
|    Isaac|  Willis|
|     Eric|    Cain|
|   Hettie| Baldwin|
|    Tommy| Wheeler|
|  Theresa|   Casey|
|     Bess| Griffin|
+---------+--------+
only showing top 20 rows

+---------+
|  column0|
+---------+
|    first|
|    Jorge|
|   Hunter|
|   Esther|
|   Dennis|
|   Nettie|
|    first|
|    Jorge|
|   Hunter|
|   Esther|
|   Dennis|

+---------+
only showing top 20 rows


